Listen events of GPS Tracker TK403A using NodeJS
I am looking for a way to get the data sent from this model of GPS Tracker for vehicles.
A DNS configuration command is sent via SMS, example: my.domain.com 9089, which specifies the domain and port where the data will be sent.
Does anyone know if it sends them through a communication with websockets, or an HTTP/S request?
The GPS Tracker model is Coban TK403A.
